# Number picker causing application to crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, numberpicker

I have an activity that displays a list of restaurant dishes. Each view of the list has a number picker associated with it. The application runs fine, however when I start the activity to display the list it crashes...

This is my class file.

```
NumberPicker np;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starters);
    createTestData();

    adapter = new MenuItemArrayAdapter(this, starters);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setMaxValue(99);
}
```

This is my xml layout file for the StartersActivity class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="670dp">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

 <include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    layout="@layout/pricebar" />
```

This is my xml layout file for the row in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numpick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dishpic"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numpick"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reviewBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_price"
    android:text="ITEM NAME"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reviewBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dishpic"
    android:text="ITEM PRICE"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reviewBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dishpic"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numpick"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dishpic"
    android:text="@string/reviewBtn" />
```

It seems to be the number picker that is causing the problem because when I take out the following code it works.

```
np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setMaxValue(99);
```

Any ideas as to what might be the problem? The error is a null pointer exception:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.waitron5/com.example.waitron5.StartersActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException**

I have a feeling it is something to do with trying to access the number picker before the list is loaded and it's not seeing it.

Comment: Did I get that right, that the layout file you have posted is not `R.layout.activity_starters`?

Comment: sorry you are right, the layout file is the layout for the row in the list. I'll post the starters layout now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Each view of the list has a number picker associated with it`

The above statement makes me believe that the NumberPickers controls should be referenced and initialized in the `MenuItemArrayAdapter` in the `getView()` method, versus in `onCreate()` how it is now:

```
np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numpick);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setMaxValue(99);
```

Comment: Each list row has its own instance of `NumberPicker`. Putting just one instance into the field of the activity does not look correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the `NumberPicker` in the `onCreate` method it would have to be defined in the main layout. Since it is not you get the NPE.

It depends what you do with the `NumberPicker` where the best place is to fetch it. It must be specific to the list item view in question.